# svn commit error

Tags: svn

I have a problem when i use svn commit to update my changes in the svn repository.

This is how i work. I have my local repository called X where i have all my folders and files necessary. I also have a local working copy Y in the current directory, the contents of which are copied over from X. So when i want to make changes to my code, i make changes to it in my local working copy Y and when its time to commit, i copy the contents of the Y folder to the X folder, so that the new changes are reflected. However when i try to run an svn commit from within X, i get an error saying that "filename.c is out of date"(where filename.c is the file i edited in Y).

What am i possibly doing wrong here ?

Comment: What is a repository and a working copy by your definition?

Comment: You need to read and work through a tutorial on SVN. None of what you're describing before the attempt to commit is the way you work with any version control system. Try the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) - it covers everything you'll normally need to know about SVN.

Comment: @Ed Heal :I'm using sn version 1.6.17(thats all i know about it)

Comment: @manijids: by repository i mean , the directory from within which i run the svn update and svn commit commands. By working copy i mean, its a copy of the repository initially. I make my changes to certain files there and copy it to my repository .

Comment: @hektor - You are doing it all wrong. Please understand the concepts and need for a version control system and also learn about SVN and then proceed.

Comment: If I wanted to write a question for the sake of totally exasperating common SVN users, this question is the way I'd go about it.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing this all wrong. You need to read up about SVN. Here is a link to a tutorial - [Tutorial for SVN](http://maverick.inria.fr/~Xavier.Decoret/resources/svn/index.html). Best to read this first and then post any questions on specifics.